# Allow a newly created table to inherit constraints from the parent table

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I have recently been allotted development tasks at my job after a couple of years providing customer training/service/support (Yay, long run paying off!) I pointed out to my supervisor and was agreed with that we need to add a couple of tables to implement a new feature in order to stay consistent in the way that our front-side application handles the information in the database.

Currently, information is stored all together in one table until it is approved by an end user to be permanently added to the database. It is possible for the information to be one of three types - Two of the three are special case scenarios that require a second level of finalization from an end user before being put into their final location. For these two that require the second level of finalization, all of the other bits and pieces of information that supplement the primary information are stored in separate tables from the primary piece.

My question is this - These secondary tables where the information temporarily resides before being finalized are basically all foreign keys. I was looking at creating the new set of tables from the existing initial tables - Is there a way during that creation for the new secondary table to inherit the constraints that are coming with the initial table columns?

While both of these particular tables are going to be small ones and I don't mind manually creating the script to add the constraints after the creation of the table, it seems like this would be valuable information to know in the future. I've looked through stack overflow, but all questions that are remotely similar are from a different version of SQL.

Additionally, this would have to work all the way back through SQL Server 2008, as we have not stopped supporting 2008 yet.

Comment: Short answer - no, there is no "inheritance" in tsql. If you want tables to have the same constraints, you need to create them separately for each table. But it sounds to me like the chosen path is more complicated than needed. A new secondary table for this special 2 types would only need the primary key of the parent (as both PK and FK in this new table) and the additional attributes needed for finalization. In that sense, the new table can be said to inherit them simply because of the PK/FK relationship. But it is not actual inheritance in the OO sense.

Comment: _"I don't mind manually creating the script to add the constraints after the creation of the table, it seems like this would be valuable information to know in the future"_ In my experience it is not, the scenarios where this would be helpful are very limited (such as one time table creation), or useful for things that probably should be done in the first place (dynamic table).

Comment: Thanks guys. I did go ahead and just manually create both the table and the constraints. I was just curious if it was possible to create a table to inherit in the fashion described, and could find literally nothing about it googling or on Stack. Figured it was worth asking!

Answer (score 0):

If you go into Management Studio, right click on the table and go to "Script Table as >"  Then "Create to >" .  That will add all the constraints.

Comment: This assumes that the table has already been fully created I believe?

Comment: Yeah I was looking at "I was looking at creating the new set of tables from the existing initial tables "